# Use second google form to fill additional columns in existing rows

Tags: forms, google-sheets, google-forms

I currently have a google form which is populating inputted information into a Google Sheet. On the google sheet I have an additional 4 columns which are not populated by the form. A few days after each form entry is added, additional content has to be added to the 4 extra columns that row. Currently, this is manually added to the spreadsheet.

How can I create a second form which identifies existing rows in which those 4 columns are blank, allows you to select one of those rows and can then populate those 4 empty columns with content entered in the second form?

Comment: How is this related to programming?

Comment: It would be very difficult, and a lot of programming to do what you want to do.  The second Form would need a way to match the current submission to the first submission.  You'd need to provide the response ID of the first submission to the second submission.  You could use the answers from first Form submission to build a Prefilled URL for the second Form, and put the response ID into an answer of the second Form.  That way you could match up the two responses.  You'd need to run an On Form Submit trigger when the second Form was submitted.  There would be no need to ask the user which row.

Answer (score 0):

To have multiple Google Forms populate to one spreadsheet you can use the `=importrange()` function. What this will do is allow you to mirror the data from one spreadsheet to another. This is more than just copying the data, it will reflect the current data in another spreadsheet. When changes are made, the mirrored data will update in the other spreadsheet.

Check the [link](http://alicekeeler.com/2015/01/08/multiple-google-forms-to-one-spreadsheet/) for complete example.